# CodeIgniter pass data from model to controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having trouble passing data from the controller to the view using Codeigniter

My model:

```
public function get_post($post_id) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE id = ? AND active ='y' LIMIT 1";
  $query = $this->db->query($sql, $post_id);
  return $query->result();
}
```

My controller:

```
public function city($post_id) {
  $this->load->model('post_model');
  $data = $this->post_model->get_post($post_id);
  $this->load->view('post_view', $data);
}
```

My view:

```
<h3 class="centered"><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/max_<?php echo $photo_name; ?>" alt="Post Photo">
<p><?php echo $city; ?>, <?php echo $state; ?>, 
[<?php echo strtoupper($gender); ?>] <?php echo date("D M j g:i a", strtotime($post_date)); ?>
```

When I do a `print_r` in the controller on `$data` I get:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [title] => Sample Title [city] => San Francisco [state] => California [gender] => F [photo_name] => 1404181142680616849.jpg [post_date] => 2014-07-01 03:21:41 [active] => y ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `return $query->result();` in your model to `return $query->row();` as right now you're getting an array wrapping the actual data you want